# What issue(s) does include_once or require_once solve?

Tags: php, include

From the php manual

> Include_once may help avoid problems such as function redefinitions, variable value reassignments, etc.

Ok, so include_once solves issues with function redefinitions, variable value reassignments, etc. but why are they an issue in the first place ?

I'm trying to understand what kind of risks are involved in redefining functions or reassigning variable values except for a decline in performance  due to additional input/output and processing ?

Is it because php parser gets confused which version of function to load/use or is the original version of the function lost once redefined?  What else and what about variable reassignments?

I do understand where to use `include` vs `include_once`.

Comment: You can't define a function twice, you'll get a fatal error.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - i understand that but is that cause php would get confused which version of function to load if redefining is allowed ?

Comment: @user481913 It wouldn't get confused, it's called ambiguity and function redefinition is not allowed in any language as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @RudiVisser Ruby lets you redefine functions :)

Comment: @BaylorRae' Interesting :) But it would still keep a reference to the original, right? PHP certainly wouldn't do this.

Comment: @RudiVisser well sort of, when "redefining" a function you can call the original function through `super`. It's not something I use very often, I just know Ruby lets you redefine function and classes openly.

Comment: @BaylorRae' Definitely interesting thanks! Not too sure I'd like that freedom, though ;-)

Comment: Question edited... please see above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the following include file, `hello.php`:

```
function hello()
{
    return 'Hello World';
}

$a = 0;
```

Now imagine the following file, `index.php`:

```
include 'hello.php';

$a = 1;
hello();

include 'hello.php';

hello();
echo $a; // $a = 0, not 1
```

Your code would now have a fatal error, since the function has been defined twice. Using `include_once` would avert this, since it would only include `hello.php` once. Also, to do with `variable value reassignment`, `$a` (should the code compile) would be reset to 0.

---

*From the comments, please consider this a side answer* - If you're looking for something where resetting a set of variables many times *was* required, I'd look to use a class for this with a method like `Reset`, you can even make it static if you didn't want to have to instantiate it, like so:

```
public class MyVariables
{
    public static $MyVariable = "Hello";
    public static $AnotherVariable = 5;

    public static function Reset()
    {
        self::$MyVariable = "Hello";
        self::$AnotherVariable = 5;
    }
}
```

Usage like:

```
MyVariables::$MyVariable = "Goodbye";
MyVariables::Reset();
echo MyVariables::$MyVariable; // Hello
```

Comment: yes quite similar to what @Zarathos below mentioned... so what's wrong or the risk if $a gets reset to 0 ?  One reason i think might be the difficulty debugging such code... what is exactly the risk if the values do change like in the above example you provided ?

Comment: There is no *risk* per se, it's just highly unrecommended for obvious reasons. An indirect risk would perhaps be multiple developers, expecting to include a file that includes a class, and end up resetting a tonne of variables in the process (Let's say the file also defined `$myvar` and the developer was using `$myvar` completely separately). Defining things in the global scope like this is obviously not recommended, either, hence we have OOP :)

Comment: My head is messed up at the moment... I need to take a break and rethink over this after a while to let it sink in... Sub-conciously I think I do agree/understand some of the reasoning you have provided but i just need it to sink in to convince me that I fully understand the reasoning behind this... Many thanks and +1 for providing a context...

Comment: @user481913 No problem, see a slight update. I think that's what you're getting at wanting to achieve..

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have an include script vars.inc.php:

```
<?php

    $firstname = 'Mike';
    $lastname = 'Smith';

?>
```

And then you have a script script.php:

```
<?php

    echo "$firstname $lastname"; // no output

    include('vars.inc.php');
    echo "$firstname $lastname"; // Mike Smith

    $firstname = "Tim";
    $lastname = "Young"; 
    echo "$firstname $lastname"; // Tim Young

    include('vars.inc.php');
    echo "$firstname $lastname"; // Mike Smith
?>
```

What happens is that if you modify your vars in code exection and then you include once again the file defining them, you are changing their content. include_once will ensure that this will never happens throwing an error.

Comment: Exactly the case I thought about... But what if I'm interested in doing something like this  or what's wrong if i temporarily need to have/use some other value for the vars other than their origional values ?

Comment: I highly discourage you from abusing of includes. This can be very dangerous and lead to unexpected results that are very hard to debug. Anyway... can you be more specific?

Comment: well it's all messed up in my head to come up with a specific case except why should i take care not to redefine functions/reassign values etc... I'll get back if i can come up with a specific case...

Comment: yes the ambiguity associated with debugging such kind of code can be one reason to avoid this though... Still thinking about other pitfalls...

Answer (score 0):

It will stop you loading pages more than once.  Typically you'll use this at the top of your pages to bring in your init, function, class files etc.

Especially useful if you are loading pages within pages dynamically.